# Can I get a cash refund from British Airways after applying for a voucher?

Tags: air-travel, cancellations, covid-19, refunds

I booked my flight back in January with BA, the flight got cancelled in March due to Covid19.

Many people have fallen into the trap they had on the website, where you try to get a cash refund and they force you to fill the form to get the voucher. So they sent me the voucher.

I tried to call in today and they said because you applied for the voucher you can't get a cash refund.

I am trying to book tickets for this month, BA don't have any flights available. The company is likely to go bust and fire all their pilots.

Is there a class action suit for this?

Is there a way to still get the cash refund?

Comment: British Airways isnt going bust - they dont have many flights right now because most destinations they fly to have heavy restrictions on them which is severely limiting ability to fly.  They will return to scheduled flying later this year, along with other airlines.

Comment: When you accept a future travel voucher, you are legally no longer in a position to demand a refund. It is in the fine print. You might still be able to get a Section 75 refund if you are in the UK and used a credit card. That said, it is highly unlikely that BA will go bankrupt, their finances are good. I am resting easy with my saved avios and a few future travel vouchers.

Comment: Even if you had originally applied for a refund your chances of getting it are small. Most airlines are desperately trying to hold onto the cash they have, even if they are legally required to refund passengers.

Comment: I did have a cancelled flight early in the COVID 19 crisis and opted for the refund (which was simple back then.) It took them 3 full months to refund the money to my credit card. Things have not improved since then.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, some of these are helpful. I am trying to explore getting a refund through my bank, which I am assuming is Section 75?